# Facebook Ads /insights endpoint action_target_id breakdown

Tags: facebook-ads-api

With the old [`/reportstats`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adreportstats/v2.3#breakdown) endpoint you could fetch actions grouped per target name by adding `action_target_name` to the group options. This would give you a list of targets and their actions. In the new API endpoint [`/insights`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/v2.4#parameters), only `action_target_id` is available as group option. The target can be anything, e.g. a post, a pixel, etc. but there is no type indication returned, so all you have is an ID and some actions...

So, when grouping actions by `action_target_id`, is there any way to get the target's name that belongs to the ID?

Comment: Assuming you have permission to see the items, you can make another call to fetch the names (and pictures, other metadata) of the IDs returned in the report - you'll likely need to do that anyway unless the name is the only field you were using from the promoted object's details

Comment: Hi @Igy, thanks for your reply!

The name is in fact the only field I was using and needed from the promoted object's details. This is why the `action_target_name` group option was so perfect. :)

Where can I make a call to in order to get the names?

Comment: most objects when retrieved include the name and ID by default, and most objects are accessible by ID directly, so if you get 12345, a call to /v2.5/12345 will return the id and name - you can ask for the other fields you want explicitly with the 'fields' param

Comment: Thanks @Igy, will implement that then. :)